# NSString from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I am trying to create a String from Array.But, there is condition to how it should be generated, as explained below.

```
NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello",@"World",nil];
[array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

This will output: Hello,World.

But, if first Item is Empty,then is there way to receive the only second one.

1. Hello , @""   => Hello
2. @"" , World   => World
3. Hello , World   => Hello,World

Comment: You can't put nil in an `NSArray`, do you mean something like `@[@"", "World"]` should yield `@"World"` instead of `",World"`.

Comment: @CarlVeazey its @"", not nil. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another way to do this is to grab a mutable copy of the array and just remove non valid objects. Something like this perhaps:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"World",nil] mutableCopy];
[array removeObject:@""]; // Remove empty strings
[array removeObject:[NSNull null]]; // Or nulls maybe

NSLog(@"%@", [array componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
```

Comment: @bbum No. It will remove any objects. Just [check the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or test the code... before you downvote.

Comment: Herp de derp.... there ya go.  You'd think I'd know that from using NSArray since 1994 (edit so I could upvote).

Comment: @bbum Happens to all of us from time to time Bill. A true gentleman... Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You cannot store `nil` values in `NSArray`<sup>*</sup>, so the answer is "no". You need to iterate the array yourself, keeping track of whether you need to add a comma or not.

```
NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString string];
BOOL first = YES;
for(id item in array) {
    if (id == [NSNull null]) continue;
    // You can optionally check for item to be an empty string here
    if (!first) {
        [res appendString:@", "];
    } else {
        first = NO;
    }
    [res appendFormat:@"%@", item];
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> `nil` values in NS collections are represented with `NSNull` objects.