# Issue in inserting comma while concatenating strings

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uilabel

In my application, I have a **address** label which holds the value of **"address1"**,  **"Address2"**, **"City"** and **"state"**. I need to insert commas between each value while displaying in the label.

But if there is no value for one string(say **"Address2"**) then an only comma should not be inserted there.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Are any of the fields compulsory or are they all optional?

Comment: The accepted answer to this question does what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366431/nsstring-from-nsarray

Comment: @Manoj: Use NSMutableString. Refer to this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @OP: this is a trivial algorithm. You just **do what you need.** You go through the fields, concatenating it to the result string, only inserting a comma if the current field is not empty. What's so hard with that?

Comment: Do you have your address1, address2, city, state and others in a dictionary?

Comment: @Ander: All are optional..

Comment: @H2CO3 : Since they all are optional fields, i might have to check some 16 conditions.. Thats y i ve posted for some easy method..

Comment: @ParthBhatt: No i have them as individual strings..

Comment: @ManojEllappan Use an array?

Comment: @ManojEllappan: Make the dictionary out of the individual strings and then refer to my answer below. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here consider that `dictLocation` is a dictionary which has Address1, Address2, City, State, Country and Zip:

Sample `dictLocation`:

> NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary
>   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"add1", @"Address1", @"add2",
>   @"Address2",@"cityname",@"City",@"state",@"StateName",@"country",@"CountryName",@"350010",@"ZipCode",nil];

Code:

```
-(NSMutableString *)createLocationAddress:(NSDictionary *)dictLocation
{
    NSMutableString *strAddress = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];

    NSString *strStreetAddress1 = @"";
    if(dictLocation != nil && [dictLocation valueForKey:@"Address1"] != nil)
    {
        strStreetAddress1 = [StringUtility trimWhiteSpaceAndNewLine:[dictLocation valueForKey:@"Address1"]];
    }

    [strAddress appendString:strStreetAddress1];


    NSString *strAddress2 = @"";
    if(dictLocation != nil && [dictLocation valueForKey:@"Address2"] != nil)
    {
        strAddress2 = [StringUtility trimWhiteSpaceAndNewLine:[dictLocation valueForKey:@"Address2"]];
    }

    if(![strAddress2 isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        if(![strAddress isEqualToString:@""])
            [strAddress appendString:@", "];
        [strAddress appendString:strAddress2];
    }


    NSString *strLocationCity = @"";
    if(dictLocation != nil && [dictLocation valueForKey:@"City"] != nil)
    {
        strLocationCity = [StringUtility trimWhiteSpaceAndNewLine:[dictLocation valueForKey:@"City"]];
    }

    if(![strLocationCity isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        if(![strAddress isEqualToString:@""])
            [strAddress appendString:@", "];
        [strAddress appendString:strLocationCity];
    }

    NSString *strLocationState = @"";
    if(dictLocation != nil && [dictLocation valueForKey:@"StateName"] != nil)
    {
        strLocationState = [StringUtility trimWhiteSpaceAndNewLine:[dictLocation valueForKey:@"StateName"]];
    }

    if(![strLocationState isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        if(![strAddress isEqualToString:@""])
            [strAddress appendString:@",\n"];
        [strAddress appendString:strLocationState];
    }

    NSString *strLocationCountry = @"";
    if(dictLocation != nil && [dictLocation valueForKey:@"CountryName"] !=nil)
    {
        strLocationCountry = [StringUtility trimWhiteSpaceAndNewLine:[dictLocation valueForKey:@"CountryName"]];
    }

    if(![strLocationCountry isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        if(![strAddress isEqualToString:@""])
            [strAddress appendString:@", "];
        [strAddress appendString:strLocationCountry];
    }

    NSString *strLocationZipcode = @"";
    if(dictLocation != nil && [dictLocation valueForKey:@"ZipCode"] != nil)
    {
        strLocationZipcode = [StringUtility trimWhiteSpaceAndNewLine:[dictLocation valueForKey:@"ZipCode"]];
    }

    if(![strLocationZipcode isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        if(![strAddress isEqualToString:@""])
            [strAddress appendString:@", "];
        [strAddress appendString:strLocationZipcode];
    }

    return strAddress;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Do let me know if you need anything else